# D3 .transition transform won't update svg group on sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, svg

Trying to sort an arrangement of svg groups vertically based on data. Building out a data-viz like so sets the initial order just fine.

```
// CREATE BOX FOR EACH PLAYER
const boxes = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(data, d => d.Player)
    .enter().append('g')
       .attr('transform', d => `translate(0,${yScale(d.Player)})`)
       .classed('player', true);
```

Creates a long list of groups with vizs, works great...

```
<g transform="translate(0,130.29702970297026)" class="player">...</g>
```

Click a sort button to run this function and attribute shows as changed in inspector but the group never physically moved. What am I missing?

```
function sortPlayers() {
  d3.selectAll('.player')
    .sort((a, b) => {
      const sortKey = 'FG%';
      return a[sortKey] - b[sortKey];
    });

  d3.selectAll('.player')
    .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr('transform', (d) => {
      const targetY = yScale(d.Player);
      // return 'translate(0,500)'; <-- Not what I wanted but worked.
      return `translate(0,${targetY})`;
    });
}
```

Above updates the following in inspector so it is sorting and updating, just not animating.

```
<g transform="translate(0,332.529702970297026)" class="player">...</g>
```

Since I had motion moving to `translate(0,500)` I looked into `d3.interpolateString(x,y)` but can't figure out how to get the pre-sort attribute in there. Not even sure if that's the solution. How do I animate a series of groups' transform translate attributes using data?

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddqkrpyL/1/).

Comment: can you post a fiddle.

Comment: Added fiddle that illustrates attribute changing and dom source reflecting new order. But actual display of elements don't animate to new order.

Comment: `selection.order()` will only change *document order*, i.e. the order the elements are inserted into the SVG DOM. This does not affect positioning, though. When trying to move the elements to their *new* positions you are actually transitioning from and to `yScale(d.Player)` which also is constant before and after the call to `.order()` for each respective element...

Comment: I guess I'm still confused how returning `translate(0,500)` will animate but `translate(0,${targetY})` will not, even though the values change in inspector.

Comment: I've discovered that `return 'translate(${targetY}, 0)';` animates but `return 'translate(0, ${targetY})';` does not.